# Scheme pass variables to a variadic function

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have the following variadic function `(define doSomething (lambda (x . rest) ...`. The function is called by using numbers, for example: `(doSomething 1 2 3 4 5)` (so with that call `x` would be `1` and `rest` would be `(2 3 4 5)`).

When I try to recursively call the function and put the second number (`2`) as `x` and `rest` as `(3 4 5)` I somehow receive the `rest` parameter as a list of list: `((3 4 5))`.

This is how I currently try to call the function again:
`(+ x (doSomething (car rest) (cdr rest)))`

It is worth mentioning that I'm using `Pretty Big`. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're mix and matching what rest is, in your first call

```
(doSomething 1 2 3 4 5)   ; x = 1  rest = '(2 3 4 5)
```

In your subsequent calls you'll end up with

```
(doSomething (car rest) (cdr rest))   ; x=2  rest = '((3 4 5))
```

because `rest` is a variadic argument, so it takes everything after the first argument and makes it a list called `rest` for you, hence the double-listing. You'll probably want to be using `apply` or something, ie something like:

```
(define doSomething (lambda (x . rest) 
                      (display x) 
                      (if (not (null? rest))
                        (apply doSomething rest)
                        #f)))
```